# If and Countif Function and Slicer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

ColumnA - Agent name (Say 1, 2, 3....)

ColumnB - Dealer Name(Say a, b, c, d, e, f, ....)

1 agent have multiple dealers, but a dealer must have one unique agent

ColumnC - Year(2016,NA)

Sample of the table:

```
Agent Dealer Year
1     AB     2016
1     MN     2016
1     XY     NA
2     CD     2016
2     EF     NA
2     GH     NA
3     RT     2016
3     TN     2016
3     RZ     2016
```

This formula helps in counting the total active agent name = total agent name minus total agent name with NA

For Agent1, active dealer count = 3-1 = 2

For Agent2, active dealer count = 3-2 = 1

For Agent3, active dealer count = 3-0 = 3

How do I get the active agent details count, agent wise.

Like For Active Agent1 = Total count of agent(1) - total year (na) for agent1

For Active Agent2 = Total count of agent(2) - total year (na) for Agent2

if and count if and counta

```
=if(A:A="AGENTNAME",(COUNTA('Working Sheet'!$C$4:$C$1048576)-COUNTIF('Working Sheet'!$C$4:$C$1048576,"NA")
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see sample data and expected output. It might be that `COUNTIFS` will do what you want, but I'm not sure I follow your explanation properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842). It allows you to look at multiple conditions at the same time. the `<>` operator inverts the match so it counts anything that isn't `NA`.

I copied your table in to columns A:C, and put the following formulas in cells F2 and G2 respectfully. (Agent is in column E)

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,"NA")
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,C:C,"<>NA")
```

This yielded the following

```
Agent   Inactive    Active
1       1           2
2       2           1
3       0           3
```

Also, just a matter of style, but if you don't need to specify a specific range of rows, you can tell it to look at the entire column. `C:C` is a lot easier to parse than `$C$4:$C$1048576`. Even if rows 1:3 have other information, as long as it doesn't match the agent name, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why I did not think it from that angle.. haha